# UIButton tags in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uibutton

I have 2 button objects (UIButton *obtn,*ebtn), I have created 12 buttons(6 buttons with 6 tag values for obtn, 6 buttons with 6 tag values for ebtn)... I have a single btnClick: method for all those 12 buttons... when i click on a button of tag value 1... Iam getting the properties of selected button to another button by using sender... I want to get the properties of unselected button (Example obtn object with tag value 3) into another button How can i get it...?

My Direct Question is: How to assign the properties of a button with a tag value to another button when it is in unselected state...

Comment: Please can you try to rephrase this question or add a diagram or something. I can't be the only one who has no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I really dont understand what you are asking

Comment: Wow @jrturton I posted that the exact same time you did

Comment: Sorry First I didn't gave Clarity to u... Now u can check the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to get a pointer to a button with a certain tag, and at the moment all you can do is get the button that has sent you the action.

The method you are looking for is `viewWithTag:`. This will get you a button (or any other view) with the tag you want. You pass this method to the superview of the button. So, in your action method (assuming all buttons are in the same superview):

```
UIView *superview = [sender superview];
UIButton *otherButton = [superview viewWithTag:3];
```

You then have `sender`, which is the button that was tapped, and `otherButton`, which is the button with tag 3. You can modify each one as you wish.

Answer (score -2):

```
// Create textfield 5
        btn_select_Country = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
        //btn_select_Client = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
        btn_select_Country.frame = CGRectMake(BTN_X_CORD, 228, BTN_WIDTH, BTN_HEIGHT);

        btn_select_Country.tag = 1;
        // [btn_select_Client setTitle:@"Button One" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn_select_Country addTarget:self action:@selector(countryListBtnTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn_Image_Select_Country= [UIImage imageNamed:@"drop-down.png"];
        [btn_select_Country setImage:btn_Image_Select_Country forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
        //btn_select_Client.tag=1205;
        [scrollview addSubview:btn_select_Country];




- (IBAction)currencyListBtnTap:(id)sender;
{
    button_Number = [sender tag];
    [self allTextFeildResignFirstResponder];


}
```